# How can I display the report information across and then down instead of just down multiple pages?

Tags: reporting-services

Using Microsoft [SQL Server Reporting Services](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Reporting_Services)  (SSRS), I'm trying to display a report that has hundreds of results. These results are 3 digits numbers and I don't want to have a 10 pages report. I want the display of the information to go Across, and the down after it reached the end of the row (let's just say I want to have 6 
results per row.

How can it be achieved?

Comment: What tool are you using to display the report?  Are we talking about a web page or what?

Comment: as others have said...we need to know what you're using for your reports...Excel?  web-page?  clay tablets?

Answer (score 3):

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2255748/how-can-i-display-the-report-information-across-and-then-down-instead-of-just-do/2257414#2257414) and it would not work using the name of the data set RowNumber("dsBlahBlah").  It would only work by using the name of the Tablix in both the column and row group.  After that, it was perfect!

Answer (score 1):

Use a matrix/tablix where x is the number of columns you want.

For the row grouping use:

```
=ceiling(rownumber("Dataset")/x)
```

For the column grouping use:

```
=((rownumber("Dataset")-1) mod x)
```